# viewDidLoad testing without Storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, uikit

I'm trying to apply the Clean Architecture as explained at [Clean Swift](http://www.clean-swift.com).

This is my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` implementation creating the UI without Storyboards or XIBs:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool 
{
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  let listBusNumbersViewController = ListBusNumbersViewController(style: .plain)
  let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: listBusNumbersViewController)
  window!.rootViewController = navigationController
  window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
  return true
}
```

This is my viewDidLoad implementation in `ListBusNumbersViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
  super.viewDidLoad()
  ListBusNumbersConfigurator.sharedInstance.configure(viewController: self)
  self.title = "Bus Numbers"
  searchController.delegate = self
  searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
  searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
  searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
  searchController.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
  searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
  self.tableView.register(ListBusNumbersTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ListBusNumbersTableViewCell")
  self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
  self.tableView.backgroundColor = .white
  fetchBusNumbersOnLoad()
}
```

And the implementation of `fetchBusNumbers`:

```
func fetchBusNumbersOnLoad()
{
  let request = ListBusNumbers.FetchBusNumbers.Request()
  output.fetchBusNumbers(request: request)
}
```

In my unit test, I need to test that output.fetchBusNumbers is being called. Here is the unit test:

```
class ListBusNumbersViewControllerTests: XCTestCase
{
  // MARK: - Subject under test

  var sut: ListBusNumbersViewController!
  var window: UIWindow!

  // MARK: - Test lifecycle

  override func setUp()
  {
    super.setUp()
    window = UIWindow()
    sut = ListBusNumbersViewController(style: .plain)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController = sut
    //setupListBusNumbersViewController()
  }

  override func tearDown()
  {
    //window = nil
    super.tearDown()
  }

  class ListBusNumbersViewControllerOutputSpy: ListBusNumbersViewControllerOutput
  {
    // MARK: - Method call expectations
    var fetchBusNumbersCalled = false

    // MARK: Spied methods
    func fetchBusNumbers(request: ListBusNumbers.FetchBusNumbers.Request)
    {
      fetchBusNumbersCalled = true
    }
  }

  // MARK: - Test setup

  //func setupListBusNumbersViewController()
  //{
  //  let bundle = Bundle.main
  //  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: bundle)
  //  sut = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListBusNumbersViewController") as! ListBusNumbersViewController
  //}

  func loadView()
  {
    window.rootViewController = sut
    RunLoop.current.run(until: Date())
  }

  // MARK: - Test doubles

  // MARK: - Tests

  func testShouldFetchBusNumbersWhenViewIsLoaded()
  {
    // Given
    let listBusNumbersViewControllerOutputSpy = ListBusNumbersViewControllerOutputSpy()
    sut.output = listBusNumbersViewControllerOutputSpy

    // When
    loadView()
    // Then
    XCTAssertNotNil(sut.view, "ListBusNumbersViewController should have been loaded")
    XCTAssert(listBusNumbersViewControllerOutputSpy.fetchBusNumbersCalled, "Should fetch bus numbers when the view is loaded")
  }
}
```

1. If I use Storyboards, I can call `ListBusNumbersConfigurator.sharedInstance.configure(viewController: self)` in `awakeFromNib`.That way it doesn't get called if I call viewDidLoad in my unit test thus allowing to use a Spy Class to test method calls. How do I acheive the same affect when I create the UI in code?
2. How do I call viewDidLoad in my unit test?

The project can be found [here](https://github.com/premedios/ETA).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: With regard to your 1st question, you can see why singletons are a bad idea when it comes to testability; You need to set things up so that `ListBusNumbersConfigurator.sharedInstance` is an appropriately instrumented class.  For the second question, `viewDidLoad` is called when the view is loaded by `loadView`.  `loadView` is triggered by the first reference to a view controller's `view` property.  So you should be able to say `let _ = sut.view` in order to trigger view loading.

Comment: Noted. Thanks. I'll restructure that.